# How to connect user directory to Apache web server

Tags: linux, apache

I am using `CentOS7` and `Apache 2.4`, for my own websites. I have two users only - `root` and - `username_one`. I set up two websites as `Name-based Virtual Hosts`, and these are `domain-one.com`, and `domain-two.com`. The default document root of the server is `"/var/www/html"`.

I created `/var/www/html/domain-one.com/public_html` and `/var/www/html/domain-two.com/public_html` directories, and chmoded them to 755. After that I created VirtualHost directives for these domains in `/etc/httpd/conf.d/domain-one.com.conf` and `/etc/httpd/conf.d/domain-two.com.conf` files with Nano.

So all the above is the most standard way of doing things.

Like I mentioned above I have `/home/user_one/public_html`, and I would like to enable this user and this directory to be able to work on these created sites. The user already has an ftp access, so I would basically want to log in through ftp with Filezilla, open `/home/user_one/public_html` to that, and create folders like this inside it:

```
/home/user_one/public_html/domain-one
/home/user_one/public_html/domain-two
```

... and after that, just upload whatever files would be needed for these websites, so:

```
domain-one.com would be /home/user_one/public_html/domain-one/index.html
```

and

```
domain-two.com would be /home/user_one/public_html/domain-two/index.html
```

How would I achieve something like this? I am working on this now, but it is kind of hard to figure it out, at this point, as I am new to Linux.

Thanks.

Comment: You have to adapt the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` setting for this to point to the two folders. In addition I would protect those folders _themselves_ to be removed by the user by means of file permissions.

Comment: A side note: you really should check if you cannot replace the outdated `ftp` protocol by something encrypted like `sftp` or `webdavs`. If you really have to stick with `ftp` (which is a nightmare for network administrators), then make sure you at least offer encryption of the data channel. Otherwise the whole world can read the passwords getting sent in plain text...

Comment: I am actually using sftp in Filezilla, I checked now, so this part is good.

Comment: I only mentioned the note because in the question you wrote that the user has ftp access. Now according to your last comment this does _not_ seem to be the case. Instead it looks like you gave ssh access (maybe reduced to sftp). You may want to correct that in your question. Note that `sftp` and `ftp` are two totally different things.